# scope of ui definitions in View

Tags: marionette

Which is correct?
The following code runs `clickedButton` when clicking on `.my-button` within
a) the whole document
b) only `#my-element`

In case the answer is a).  How to do b)?

```
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  el: '#my-element',

  ui: {
    button: '.my-button'
  },

  events: {
    'click @ui.button': 'clickedButton'
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is exactly B.
In BackboneJS's delegateEvents, there is scope of DOM when bind events to elements, the code like this:

```
this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
```

You could run this:
HTML is

```
<button class="my-button">Click Me - 1</button>
<div id="my-element">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="my-button">Click Me - 2</button>
</div>
```

Scripts is

```
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  el: '#my-element',

  template: false,

  ui: {
    paragraph: 'p',
    button: '.my-button'
  },

  events: {
    'click @ui.button': 'clickedButton'
  },

  clickedButton: function(evt) {
    console.log('I clicked the button ['+$(evt.target).html()+']!');
  }
});
```